# Swift 3 - Como redimensionar UITableView automaticamente

Tags: swift, uitableview

Como redimensionar automaticamente um UITableView de acordo com a quantidade de conteúdo no mesmo?
Quero fazer algo como o que dá pra fazer com um UiTextView:

```
MyTextView.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Sua pergunta nao faz muito sentido porque a UITableView é feita pra acomodar infinitos elementos e mostra-los com scroll. Ou voce esta falando dos elementos dentro do contentView dentro da tableCell?

Comment: Não @leofontes, se trata do tableView mesmo. De alguma forma, existe como calcular a altura total das linhas de dentro desse tableView? O que quero fazer é pegar esse tamanho, setar {tableView.frame.size.height} e colocar isso tudo em um scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce precisa pegar a altura da celula, pedir pro array que voce usa como dataSource o `count` e entao setar o tamanho no frame, segue uma ideia:

```
var tamanhoCell = tableView.rowHeight
var count = seuArray.count
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tamanhoCell * count);
```

Ainda acho que sua pergunta nao faz muito sentido, porque o TableView foi feito pra acomodar os itens ali dentro sem aumentar sua altura, mas boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

Simples, basta inserir este código no seu viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 76
```

Na primeira linha, ele vai dimensionar automaticamente.
Na segunda, você estima a altura mais utilizada. Na teoria, você precisa somente da primeira, mas eu recomendo utilizar as duas.

Abraços.